# Create named list from matrix using rpy2

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, rpy2

I have a `2D numpy` array which I converted to `R` `matrix` and now I need to convert it further to `named list`:

```
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
nr,nc = counts.shape
r_mtx = robjects.r.matrix(counts, nrow=nr, ncol=nc)
```

So, I got the matrix `r_mtx`, but I am not sure how to make a named list out of it similar to how we do it in `R`:

```
 named_list <- list(counts=mtx)
```

I need it to feed into `SingleCellExperiment` object to do dataset normalization:

https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/scran/inst/doc/scran.html

I tried using `rpy2.rlike.container` both `TaggedList` and `OrdDict` but can't figure out how to apply them to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I solved it (avoiding convertion of `numpy` array to `r` matrix), straight making the named list from the `numpy` array:

```
named_list = robjects.r.list(counts=counts)
```

Where `counts` is a `2D` `numpy` array